# Complexity of insert(0, c) operation on StringBuffer: is it O(1)?

Tags: java

I am aware that the append() operation for StringBuffer takes O(1) time and it avoids the overhead of creating multiple copies of String objects as compared to String concatenation.

What about insert(int offset, char c)?

I need to repeatedly call this operation so as to add in new characters one by one in a reversed order to the StringBuffer object. For example,

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.insert(0, 'c');
sb.insert(0, 'b');
sb.insert(0, 'a');
System.out.println(sb.toString()); //prints out "abc";
```

In an ideal situation, each insert(0, c) is supposed to be O(1) if internally that StringBuffer object looks like a linked list of characters. I wish to confirm if this is really the case.

Comment: You can have a look at the code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.insert%28int%2Cjava.lang.String%29), it uses System.arrayCopy so the complexity is 0(n).

Comment: Why do you care?  If you're doing lots of inserts into gigantic StringBuffers you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @HotLicks Why must it be something wrong? Sometimes we need to append a string repeatedly but do it in a reversed direction; that means you can only know the last character first before you know the previous characters.

Comment: @KubaSpatny Interesting. This is `AbstractStringBuffer`; although it is not StringBuffer that we use from the standard java.lang package, I guess the implementation of StringBuffer is roughly similar.

Comment: If one needed to do it in reverse order the way to go would be to accumulate the individual strings in an array or list and then spin backwards through the list to add to a StringBuilder at the end.  This would be much more efficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it's an implementation detail - but I wouldn't *expect* it to be a linked list of characters. I'd expect it to be a `char[]` with a length, basically - like an `ArrayList`, but for characters. So inserting a character at the start of the buffer means copying all the rest of the data.

That's been the basis of every implementation I've seen - a linked list of characters would have *huge* memory (and allocation time) costs compared with the more common implementation. A list or tree structure comprising of references to *portions* of strings (see ["rope"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure))) wouldn't have the same costs, but I haven't personally seen a Java implementation of `java.lang.StringBuilder` or `java.lang.StringBuffer` which uses ropes.  So yes it is `O(n)` at least almost always.

Comment: Interesting for the data structure of "rope" but I guess that that would make append() operation (the most frequently used operation for StringBuffer) to cost more than O(1), because you might need to keep balancing the tree structure while appending.

Comment: @Erencie: I don't know much about the details of ropes, but it would definitely be a trade-off. Even with `StringBuilder`, append is not actually O(1) - at best, it's O(N) in the size of data that you're appending, and at worst it needs to create a copy when expanding the buffer.

Answer (score 11):

The `insert` operation on a `StringBuffer` is O(n).  This is because it must shift up to `n` characters out of the way to make room for the element to be inserted.

```
"bc"
insert(0, 'a') => "_bc" => "abc"
```

You can get around this by not using `insert`.  You can iterate the letters in the reverse order, and then you can call the O(1) `append` method.

The `StringBuffer` class is a subclass of `AbstractStringBuilder`, which defines a `char[]` to hold the characters.  It uses `System.arraycopy` to move the existing characters out of the way on a call to `insert`.

Comment: May I ask how you know the `StringBuffer` is a subclass of `AbstractStringBuilder`? I check from this link [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) but I couldn't find that it extends `AbstractStringBuilder`.

Comment: Ok I guess you find it from the open jdk [StringBuffer](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) which does provide the implementation details. And it is using `System.arraycopy(value, offset, value, offset + 1, count - offset);` to do the elements shifting.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find it in the documentation, but it *most probably* is not O(1), because a `StringBuffer` internally maintains a `char[]` buffer. So for a sequence of `n` characters, the total time required for these operations is O(n^2), as each `insert(0, c)` requires shifting all current contents by 1.

A more efficient way of doing this would be to just append all characters using `append`, and at the end use `sb.reverse()`. The overall complexity for that is O(n) - amortized O(1) for each `append`, and O(n) for the reverse.

Additionally, unless you have multiple threads accessing your `StringBuffer`, you might want to consider replacing it with a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Comment: I don't get your point. That's why I put the word "unless" at the beginning of the sentence..?

Comment: how is shifting a string a `O(n^2)` operation? Isn't that `O(n)`? Thanks

Comment: The individual insert/shift is O(n), a sequence of n insert(0, c) calls starting with an empty StringBuilder is O(n^2)

Answer (score 1):

Well the internal datastructure of StringBuilder is an array and not node linking to other nodes (linked list), so the answer is no - it will not be 0(1)